# Is there an elegant solution for handling callbacks from external devices in clean architecture?

Tags: callback, architecture, external, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

I am building a complex system, based on clean architecture (https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), using many external components, for example a payment terminal. The mentioned payment terminal has a library which contains basic functions, including a place to pass a callback, so that the terminal can inform about the progress of the transaction, e.g. (insert pin or remove the payment card).

Let's consider a scenario:

1. User presses the button "Perform transaction", using some kind of adapter system notices that user wants to perform transaction.
2. System using other kind of adapter calls external API and tells it "perform transaction".
3. Now we would like to inform user about the progress... via external API callback.

> in order to use a callback API, one or more of our application classes must implement the callback method(s), and must therefore conform to some abstraction defined by the API’s provider. So our classes must depend on the API. Which means that the API can’t be easily mocked or stubbed. We have to treat our callback objects as being part of the adapter for that API, and test the rest of the application by mocking or stubbing them.

On one hand, I would not want to make the architecture dependent on an external API, but creating new entities specifically to handle API events seems over-engineered to me.

Comment: Could you please do a concrete clear question of what do you want/need? A diagram of your system could help also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a progress interface in the use case layer, since it reports progress of the use case.

Then I would implement a progress presenter and pass it to the use case when it is called from the controller.

The use case can then pass the progress to the payment terminal adapter through it's interface.

```
+------------+     +-------------------+  <<create>>  +------------+
| View Model | <-- | ProgressPresenter | <----------  | Controller |
+------------+     +---------+---------+              +------------+
                             |                              |
UI                           |                              |
=============================|==============================|==========
Use Case                     V                              V
                       +----------+                    +----------+
                       | Progress |                    | Use Case |
                       +----------+                    +----------+
                             ^                              |
                             |                              V
                             |                     +-----------------+
                             |                     | PaymentTerminal |   
                             |                     +-----------------+
                             |                              | 
=============================|==============================|==========
External                     |                              V
                             |                  +------------------------+
                             +------------------| PaymentTerminalAdapter |
                                                +------------------------+
```

In a rich client application the `ViewModel` is usually connected to the UI component via an observer relationship and will cause the UI to update when the `ViewModel` changes. In an web application you either have to do this through some kind of websocket or save the progress in some kind of storage (session or database) and let the client poll the value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  In reference to your diagram, 'PaymentTerminalAdapter' have to translate external API to domain counterpart. So for example, if terminal have 3 callback statuses in described enum (ENTER_CARD, ENTER_PIN, REMOVE_CARD) now we have to create domain entity which which will be the equivalent of terminal statuses. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: That's right. Or you create a `TerminalProgress` that provides the methods `enterCard()`, `enterPin()`, `removeCard()` and the presenter implementation does what it needs to update the view model.

Comment: @akkolyth I posted yet another answer that might help you make a good decision.

Answer (score 0):

I re-thought my previous answer. There is maybe a better solution, because the `Terminal` looks like just another I/O device. If this solution is suitable for you depends on how the terminal api is designed.

Since I don't know how your api really works, I will assume something. Maybe it fits your requirements or gives you new ideas.

Create a terminal adapter when the terminal session starts and connect it
to the presenter.
You can the call the use cases and pass them a `PaymentTerminal` interface.

```
+-----------+                    
| ViewModel |
+-----------+
      ^
      |
+-----------+     +-----------------+      +------------+
| Presenter | <-- | TerminalAdapter | <--- | Controller |
+-----------+     +-----------------+      +------------+
                           ^                     |
===========================|=====================|===============
                           |                     V
                     +----------+          +----------+
                     | Terminal | <------- | Use Case |
                     +----------+          +----------+
```

Some pseudo controller code:

```
public void startPaymentSession(){
    PaymentModel paymentModel = .. // get the model
    PaymentPresenter paymentPresenter = new PaymentTerminalPresenter(paymentModel);

    this.paymentTerminalAdapter = new PaymentTerminalAdapter();
    this.paymentTerminalAdapter.setCallbacks(paymentPresenter);

    UseCase uc = new UseCase(this.paymentTerminalAdapter);
    uc.execute();
}
```

> In this case we connect 'external layer' Terminal API using adapter (Terminal API progress entities to Presenter progress entities) de facto bypassing the use case layer. Whether this would cause some sort of architectural breach? Anyway, personally, this solution seems more reasonable to me.

Since I don't know the terminal api you are using I can only guess...

To me it looks like the terminal api is mixing view and application logic things. There is some kind of callback registration used to inform the user and other methods that handle application logic. Thus I would connect the termial api UI part to the presenter and pass the application logic part (as an interface) to the use case. In this case I think it's not an architectural breach, because a part of the terminal adapter is an I/O device.

This might be wrong, because it's based on my assumptions. Nevertheless I wanted to show another way for situations where my assumptions are true.

Finally I think it doesn't really matter if we look at the terminal api as an external service or an I/O device. For me one goal of the architecture is more important - the testability of the use cases, the presenter and so on.

Comment: Interesting, on one hand thanks to this solution we don't have to define more domain entities, which would correspond to those of the terminal API (it's unfortunately a forced boilerplate) so that's fine. However in this case we connect 'external layer' Terminal API using adapter (Terminal API progress entities to Presenter progress entities) de facto bypassing the use case layer. Whether this would cause some sort of architectural breach? Anyway, personally, this solution seems more reasonable to me.